# How to post an image with no text?

Tags: discussion, support

Some puzzles are self-explanatory and need only an image.  For example, see the [fish](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117060/a-missing-link-in-the-food-chain) and the [star](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118123/it-comprises-that-which-composes-it).

However, the question review software insists that I include at least 30 characters of text.  I've tried unobtrusive text such as strings of spaces or hyphens, but it is not fooled.

Is there a way around it?  How can I post an image only?

I contacted Stack Exchange directly, but they suggested I post on Puzzling Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer is a [frame challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263661/) focusing on the examples of just-image questions given.*

Both of those puzzles are self-explanatory **as long as the user can see the image**. But that is not a given. For example, some users are blind/visually-impaired; without a textual transcription they would have no way of understanding or enjoying the puzzle. The internet is inaccessible enough; let's not make it more so by denying these people written representations of images when possible. Additionally, the image may be blocked by a firewall (government censorship, school content monitor, etc.) and as a result not display.

You **should** take the time to type out a text representation of the puzzle, making it solvable without the image, even if to you (a sighted user able to access imgur.com) the image is "self-explanatory". By doing so you will easily bypass the character limit.

Comment: I strongly agree with this answer _for those two specific questions_, where the visual presentation is mostly distraction (perhaps deliberately so) from the actual puzzle, but not so much _in general_; there are some genuinely visual puzzles that could not possibly be represented faithfully in textual form, and surely some of those could take the form of a single image with no text.

Comment: Though surely in general it can't be so hard to find a few words of explanation. And if it's the must-be-some-text requirement that led SlowMagic to provide a textual version of the second puzzle they linked to, why then it's done some good :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I have edited to make more clear that I am focusing on the specific questions presented and saying that they are not valid as examples of questions which should/could be just images

Comment: I agree that there are purely visual puzzles that can consist of images only and that cannot be made accessible to the blind. In that case, the 30 required characters could be used to write a brief footnote explaining that. It may spoil the presentation, but it may also forestall comments that request a text version.